# How to "Select all and Copy" on the Error List of Visual Studio using Visual Studio2019 Macros

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-macros

I know that we can do a Ctrl A + Ctrl C on the error list to copy all items in the error list. I want to automate this using Visual Studio Macros.

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll");
```

is not  working for me. It says "Command Edit.SelectAll is not available".
What could be done to do a  Ctrl A operation using Visual Studio Macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SendKeys to emulate Ctrl A when the Error List window is selected:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^a");
```

Comment: Do I have to import any library or anything as such? Because it says " 'System' is undefined"

Comment: It is in assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll. What do you use to create the macro?

Comment: I am using JavaScripts, because macros are recorded as JavaScript files that call VS DTE APIs

Comment: Macros for Visual Studio extension probably doesn't support it.

As an alternative, you can use SendKeys with my Visual Commander extension.

Comment: Thanks Sergey Vlasov! This worked. Further, is it possible to run this macro from the CLI? I will keep Visual Studio open, but I would like to run this from the CLI. How do we do that?

Comment: @VidhathriAvadhany Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740973/how-to-trigger-a-visual-studio-macro-from-the-command-prompt/